# Matching a URL Encoded e-mail address in C#

Tags: c#, .net, urlencode, email-spam

I did some searching and didn't quite figure out why my solution is not working. Basically I need to take a string (which is HTML code) parse it and look for mailto links (which I then want to replace as part of an obfuscation). Here is what I have thus far:

```
    string text = "<p>Some Person<br /> Person's Position<br />p. 123-456-7890<br /> e. <a  title=\"Email Some Person\" target=\"_blank\" href=\"mailto:someperson%40domain.com\">someperson@domain.com</a></p>";
    text = Server.UrlDecode(text);
    string safeEmails = Regex.Replace(text, "(<a href=\"mailto:)(.*?)(%40)(.*?)(\">)(.*?)(</a>)", "<a class=\"mailme\" href=\"$2*$4\">$6</a>");
    Response.Write( Server.HtmlDecode(safeEmails));
```

The text is coming out of a WYSIWYG text editor (Telrik RadEditor for those familiar) and for all intents and purposes I don't have access to be able to control what is coming out of it.

Basically I need to find and replace any:

```
<a href="mailto:someone%40domain.com">someone@domain.com</a>
```

With:

```
<a class="mailme" href="someone@domain.com">someone@domain.com</a>
```

---

Some background: I am attempting to create a mailto link that will avoid detection by harvesters. The problem is that I receive a string with the e-mail as a standard mailto link. I cannot control the incoming string, so the mailto will always be an unprotected mailto. My object is to find all of them, obfuscate them, then use JavaScript to "fix" the link so that human vistors can easily use the mailto links. I am open to new approaches as well as modifications to the above code.

Comment: Reminds me of a song. Anything you can do they can do better. Is that the one. Remember you have limited resources. Harvesters tend towards unlimited resources.

Comment: Email harversters aren't limited to looking for _mailto:_ prefixes in your hrefs...

Comment: Both of you have very valid points, but neither of them really help me. I am attempting to obfuscate mailto because that is the only thing I can look for. The real problem is I can't seem to get .Net to find the matches with the url encoded emails in them.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex or the HTML agility pack to find and obfuscate all your mailto. If you want a good obfuscation try reading [ten methods to obfuscate e-mail addresses compared](http://techblog.tilllate.com/2008/07/20/ten-methods-to-obfuscate-e-mail-addresses-compared/)

**EDIT:**
sorry, from the first version of your question I didn't get you had a problem in making your regex work. Since you're usign a WYSIWYG text editor, I think the HTML that comes out of it should be pretty "regular", so you may be fine using a regex.
You can try changing your Replace line like this:

```
string safeEmails = Regex.Replace(text, "href=\"mailto:.*\">(.*)</a>", "class=\"mailme\" href=\"$1\">$1</a>");
```

Comment: Unfortunately most of those require me to alter the mailto link (essentially what I am attempting to do in my .Net code above) but as I said, I don't have control of what comes out of the text editor. I also can't say to my customers "you need to type this instead" unfortunately, they aren't that savvy. So I'm still stuck at the whole, I can't find the links because .Net's RegEx doesn't seem to want to find the url encoded emails. :-(

Comment: @Joel if you always have the email address of the person in the text of the mailto link you can capture it from there. I've included an example in my answer